# Wireframe isosurface with Mayavi

Tags: python, mayavi

The [`mesh`](http://docs.enthought.com/mayavi/mayavi/auto/mlab_helper_functions.html#mesh) function in Mayavi accepts a `representation` keyword that allows the surface to be viewed as the triangulated wireframe mesh. How can achieve a similar result for an iso surface using `mlab.pipeline.iso_surface` or `mlab.contour3d`?

For example, I'd like to achieve something to the effect:

```
import numpy as np
from mayavi import mlab

# Create image volume with sphere as zero level surface.
x,y,z = np.mgrid[-20:21, -20:21, -20:21].astype(np.float)
vol = np.sqrt(x**2 + y**2 + z**2) - 7

# Visualize the level surface.
sf = mlab.pipeline.scalar_field(vol)
mlab.pipeline.iso_surface(sf, contours=[0.0],
                          representation='wireframe')
mlab.show()
```

Of course, this code doesn't run because the `representation` keyword argument doesn't exist for the `iso_surface` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've figured it out by using the `mlab.view_pipeline()` command and using the GUI to explore the properties of the pipeline created.

The wireframe can be achieved by:

```
sf = mlab.pipeline.scalar_field(vol)
iso = mlab.pipeline.iso_surface(sf, contours=[0.0])

# Added line.
iso.actor.property.representation = 'wireframe'

mlab.show()
```

which results in

[image]